# CodeIgniter - order my 'posts' by month?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, count, group-by

In my website I'd like to create an 'archive' list to categorise my posts.

My `posts` table is set up like so:
**id | post_title | post | pubdate | year | month**

Currently this **model** function pulls the posts:

```
function getNews(){
     $data = array();
     $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
     $Q = $this->db->get('posts');
     if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
       foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
         $data[] = $row;
       }
    }
    $Q->free_result();  
    return $data;
}
```

However, is it possible I can create a list like the following?

```
July (12)

June (5)

May (2)
```

So it lists the month and the number of posts within that month?

All my attempts thus far have ended in frustration and tears. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT  `year`,`month`,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `posts` WHERE `month` =p.`month`) AS c
FROM `posts` p  GROUP BY p.`month` ORDER BY `month`

function getNews(){
 $data = array();

 $Q = $this->db->query('SELECT `year`,`month`,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `posts` WHERE `month`=p.`month`) AS c FROM `posts` p  GROUP BY p.`month`ORDER BY `month`');
 if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
   foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
     $data[] = $row;
   }
}
$Q->free_result();  
return $data;
}
```

Comment: A slight amendment to dianuj's answer is to introduce year as well otherwise you end up with all the months grouped together from every year.

    SELECT `month`,`year`,(
        SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `test` 
        WHERE `month` = p.`month`) AS c FROM `test` p 
        ORDER BY p.`year`, p.`month`;

Comment: @mplf you are right i agree but he didn't mentioned in his question although i will add the column in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this later today and reply to you. Thanks again for your speedy response.

Answer (score 1):

This is not codeigniter related but i'll answer you anyway.

use SELECT Count(*) then order by 'month', write a query and run it using this

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html